# Intellilj Idea TODO search space to include other file types, e.g. .md and .asciidoc

Tags: intellij-idea

`IntelliJ Idea` does not seem to be searching thru `.md` and `.asciidoc` files.

I'd like to maintain a list of 'TODO's in such files (because we can add more, well-formatted-for-readability information in such files).

If I change the file extension to `.txt` then the `TODO`s appear in the TODO tool window, but if I change it back to the `.md` or `.asciidoc` the TODOs disappear.

Is there a way to configure the scope of the `TODO` search algorithm in `Idea`?

The present `TODO` setup window allows us to configure the *search pattern* and the filters for pruning the tool window display list.  It does not allow us to extend the search space of the `TODO` list to other file types in the project space.

Comment: I'm making do for now by just renaming the files to the .txt extension. Other workarounds are: do a command-line grep, or: use CTRL-SHIFT-F (find in file) which shows a nice in-context display.

Comment: TODO problem in Markdown should be fixed in 2018.2: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-18408

Comment: As of today TODO works fine in md, adoc and txt file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today TODO works fine in md, adoc and txt file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[JetBrains docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2019.3/using-todo.html?utm_source=product&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=IC&utm_content=2019.3) state

> These patterns can be used inside line and block comments of any supported file type.

Markdown is a supported file type (looking at v2019.3.3), so what's the problem?

The problem is that markdown files do not support either line comments nor block comments.

Answer (score -1):

TODO recognition is provided by the plugins supporting each file type. If you install the Markdown Support and AsciiDoc plugins, you should get correct TODO display for those file types.

Comment: Both Asciidoc as well as both Markdown plugins (navigator and support)  are already installed.  I'm using the latest Ultimate version.